# Possible values of $\det \left( A \right)$ and $\text{rank}\left( {{A_{3 \times 3}}} \right)$ of an ${A_{n \times n}}$ matrix for which $A A = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What are all the possible values of $\det \left( A \right)$ and $\operatorname{rank}\left( {{A_{3 \times 3}}} \right)$ of an ${A_{n \times n}}$ matrix for which $A A = A$?

It looks easy but I noticed that this not only applies for all the identity matrices ${I_n}$ but also for all the zero matrices ${O_n}$.
We are looking for all the matrices for which
$$A A = A$$
$$A A - A = O$$
$$A A - A {I_n} = O$$
$$A \left( {A - {I_n}} \right) = O$$
So it seems that $A = O$ or $A = {I_n}$ are the only ones.
Then we can conclude that since both of these matrices are already in the row echelon form, their determinans well be equal to the product of the values on their diagonals which are 
$$\det \left( {{O_{n \times n}}} \right) = \prod\limits_{}^n 0  = 0$$
$$\det \left( {{E_n}} \right) = \prod\limits_{}^n 1  = 1$$
The rank, I suppose, can only be
$$\operatorname{rank}\left( {{O_{3 \times 3}}} \right) = 0,$$
$$\operatorname{rank}\left( {{I_{3 \times 3}}} \right) = 3.$$

Are there any matrices which I have missed? It doesn't seem right that there are really only these two.

Comment: @amd What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that determinant is multiplicative:

If $A^2 = A$, then $\det(A^2) = \det(A)$, but $\det(A^2) = \det(A)^2$, so this equation gives us $\det(A)^2 = \det(A) \implies \det(A) = 0 \text{ or } \det(A) = 1$. This holds regardless of the value of $n$.

You're right that such a matrix must satisfy the equation $A^2 - A = 0$, or in other words its minimal polynomial is either $A$, $A-I$, or $A^2 - A$.

If the minimal polynomial is $A$, then the matrix is the zero matrix and has rank $0$.

If the minimal polynomial is $A-I$ then the matrix is the identity matrix, which has rank $3$.

Lastly, if the minimal polynomial is $A^2 - A$, then $A$ is diagonalizable because the roots of this polynomial are distinct. Then since all eigenvalues of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$, $A$ has Jordan form a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $0$ and $1$. They're not all $0$ and not all $1$, otherwise we're in one of the above cases. But note that any other combination results in a nonzero, nonidentity matrix satisfying $A^2 = A$, so in this case the rank can be either $1$ or $2$.

Thus there is no restriction on the rank of $3\times3$ matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = A$.

Comment: So for all the diagonasible ${A_{3 \times 3}}$ matrices the characteristic polynomial is $cha{r_A}\left( x \right) = \left( {{\lambda _1} - {a_1}} \right)\left( {{\lambda _2} - {a_2}} \right)\left( {{\lambda _3} - {a_3}} \right)$ where ${a_1},{a_2},{a_3} \in $  and ${\lambda _1},{\lambda _2},{\lambda _3}$ are the eigenvalues, hence all the possible solutions of this equation can be the $rank\left( A \right)$?

Comment: Not quite. The characteristic polynomial can't tell you the rank of the matrix. The idea was to show that (1) any matrix satisfying $A^2 = A$ is diagonalizable, (2) the eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$, (3) the number of $1$s is the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Where did you get that any matrix for which ${A^2} = A$ is diagonalizable? So what values can $rank\left( A \right)$ have? I'm confused.

Comment: My answer says that the rank can be anything between $0$ and $3$. The reason that such a matrix is diagonalizable is because any choice for its minimal polynomial doesn't have a double root! A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots.

Comment: I've never heard of the minimal polynomial thing. We have been told that in order for a matrix $A$ to be diagonalizable, for every ${\lambda _i}$ the $\dim \left( {\ker \left( {A - {I_n}{\lambda _i}} \right)} \right)$ must be equal to ${{\lambda _i}'s}$ multiplicity. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use $A(A - I_n) = 0$ to conclude that $A=0, A=I_n$ are the *only* solutions. In algebraic terms, the ring of matrices has *zero divisors*, e.g. there are non-zero $A$ and $B$ so that $AB = 0$.

You *can* however conclude that:
$$
  AA = A 
\\ \Rightarrow det(AA) = det(A)
\\ \Rightarrow det(A)det(A) = det(A)
$$
So that either $det(A) = 0$ or $det(A) = 1$.

To explore the rank question, consider the matrix $A$ which has a $1$ in the upper-right position, and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: 1) Why can't I though? Isn't that how equations work? 2) How do I get all the ${3 \times 3}$ matrices for which $AA = A$ then?

Comment: No, see my addition about "zero divisors". Basically, for matrices, $AB =0$ can happen even if $A$ and $B$ are both non-zero. Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Equations in integral domains, like the real numbers and polynomial rings, yes. Like Baron writes, though, that's now how matrix equations work. For example, $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ is not the zero matrix, but its square is zero.

Answer (score 0):

if $A \neq I_n$ then $det(A)=0$ because let $B=A-I_n\neq 0$ $AB=0$ so(1) $A$ isn't invertible.

(1) : if $A$ invertible then $A^{-1}AB=0$ so $B=0$ impossible !

the rank can be, $0...n$ : get $A=diag(1,..,1,0,..,0)$